# Starting Petrel 2014 via the command line cannot find licence

Tags: ocean, petrel

With previous versions of Petrel with a basic developer licence, the application could be started from the command line with

```
petrel.exe -licensePackage Package1
```

That works just fine for Petrel 2011, 12 and 13. However with Petrel 2014, this approach fails with a message that the licence doesn't exist or has expired.

Starting Petrel without parameters results in a new licence dialogue appearing, which lists the package as `Bundle 1`. specifying `Bundle 1` and `Bundle1` after `-licensePackage` makes no difference when trying to start from the command line though.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how licence packages are now specified for Petrel 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the command line, you pass the name of a *profile*, not a license or bundle.
You need to save a profile first:  At the "License selection" dialog, select the licenses you need in the license profile, click the "Save selection as profile" button, and name your new profile (without spaces).  Then pass this name as the `-licensePackage` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The license stack was reengineered in Petrel 2014 and the notion of a default license packaged, e.g. Package1, is no longer supported.

"Bundle 1" fails because it is just a display name. You can, however, find the actual bundle id to use by right-clicking the bundle in the license dialog and select **List users...**. Look for the *License id* in the **License users** dialog that appears. The bundle id should look something like 
**Petrel_123456789_MAMAMAMA/aUA** and use this as the **-licensePackage** argument.

```
petrel.exe -licensePackage Petrel_123456789_MAMAMAMA/aUA
```

Alternatively, you can create a profile in the license dialog and name it Package1, and use this as the **-licensePackage** argument.

```
petrel.exe -licensePackage Package1
```

Comment: I've already used Robert's solution and so accepted it as the "right answer", but definitely upvoting this one too as it supplies extra info, re using the real name of the bundle, which may be useful to others. Thanks.